# SQL Server 2008: Only one result, joining 3 tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have the following databases:

**IMAGE UPDATED**

[image]

```
    SELECT
        l.FECHA, nc.IdNumeroControlTrabajador AS ENLACE,
        t.RFC, t.Homonimia AS HOM,
        t.ApellidoPaterno, t.ApellidoMaterno,
        t.Nombre, l.IMPORTE,
        cp.NombreOrgano AS DEPENDENCIA, l.OBSERVACIONES,
        l.FECHA_INICIAL, l.FECHA_FINAL,
        MAX (cn.FechaIngresoGobierno)
    FROM
        CapturaFAIFAP.dbo.Laudos AS l
    LEFT JOIN FAIFAPparalelo.dbo.NumeroControlTrabajadores AS nc ON l.ID = nc.idTrabajador
    LEFT JOIN FAIFAPparalelo.dbo.ClaveNominalTrabajadores AS cn ON l.ID = cn.idTrabajador
    LEFT JOIN FAIFAPparalelo.dbo.Trabajadores AS t ON l.ID = t.idTrabajador
    LEFT JOIN FAIFAPparalelo.dbo.ClaveProgramatica AS cp ON cn.idClaveProgramatica = cp.idClaveProgramatica
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            cp.NombreOrgano,
            MAX (cnt.FechaIngresoGobierno) AS fecha
        FROM
            FAIFAPparalelo.dbo.ClaveNominalTrabajadores as cnt
        GROUP BY
            cp.NombreOrgano
    ) AS j ON (
        cp.NombreOrgano = j.NombreOrgano
        AND j.fecha = cn.FechaIngresoGobierno
    )
    GROUP BY
        l.FECHA, nc.IdNumeroControlTrabajador, t.RFC,
        t.Homonimia, t.ApellidoPaterno, t.ApellidoMaterno,
        t.Nombre,l.IMPORTE,cp.NombreOrgano,l.OBSERVACIONES,
        l.FECHA_INICIAL,l.FECHA_FINAL,cn.FechaIngresoGobierno
```

I need to unify the query. The huge query i put in code, and a similar query in the image. If i join the tables ClaveNominal and ClaveProgramatica i have duplicities, because sometimes the persons have 2 ClavesProgramaticas, due to the system I use, not delete or update the current registry, just puts in inactive and adds a new one active, and i can't make the condition to activo because, that represents if the person still works here.

Comment: I don't understand what this means:   `with the selected "max(FechaIngresoGobierno)"`.   I don't see that text anywhere in your query or data.

Comment: Well, "max(FechaIngresoGobierno" this is what i been trying. I select the maximum date from ClaveNominalTrabajadores, to get only one "NombreOrgano as Dependencia"...
I wish I could explain correctly... The table "ClaveNominalTrabajadores" has the job position updates from one person, but the system doesn't erase, just mark one registry as inactive and add new one. This is why I have duplicities, because i can't get a simple join... 
I know I have to select de max(FechaIngresoGobierno) and join to the table, but i don't know how...

I apologise, to confuse you, my english isn't so good.

Comment: where's `FechaIngresoGobierno`? Also it would help if you post the error message.

Comment: FechaIngresoGobierno it's in ClaveNominalTrabajadores. I'm redoing my query.
And i'll edit the original post, because I see i don't explain correctly.

Comment: I redid my query, showing and trying what I want, basicly is this part my problem:

`LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            cp.NombreOrgano,
            MAX (cnt.FechaIngresoGobierno) AS fecha
        FROM
            FAIFAPparalelo.dbo.ClaveNominalTrabajadores as cnt
        GROUP BY
            cp.NombreOrgano
    ) AS j ON (
        cp.NombreOrgano = j.NombreOrgano
        AND j.fecha = cn.FechaIngresoGobierno
    )`